# A mind-blowing riddle!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> A healthy start to begin with 
>   A friend you’ll meet midway 
>   In the end he becomes a tree 
>   You’ll soon be blown away

What word is referred here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is...

> Napalm

A healthy start to begin with

> Taking a `nap` can be good for your health, and it's the beginning of the word.

A friend you’ll meet midway

> Another word for friend is `pal`, and it's in the middle of the word.

In the end he becomes a tree

> A `palm` is a kind of tree, and it's at the end of the word.

You’ll soon be blown away

> `Napalm` can quite literally blow you away.